# Adding more cuts not creating more round object when using curve modifier on specific object

Tags: modifiers, shaders, topology

I needed more detail in this barrel that I made from flat plane and using curve modifier to bend it,
but when I add more cutts they are ignored when bending and the shape stays the same as if they were not there. Also when I fast created new model it works just as expected and I have no idea why on my original model they are not working. There is also a problem with both of them creating these vertical distortions when shade smoothing.

.blend if needed:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1I_9nzNFiBAv7eToh8vH_j0HR5IoTEW5d?usp=sharing
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I found-all that that unnecessary loopcuts were causing the issue. It is probably because you used mirror modifiers to make the barrel. *Mirror modifier just make a duplicate of the mesh and mirrors it. It does not merge the vertices to the original mesh.*

In your case the easiest way to solve it is by selecting all those edges (which you have beveled) except any one among them by  <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> + **RMB** and then delete them by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>.**Dont forget to switch off all the modidifiers except *curve modifier* before selecting**
[image]
[image]
[image](Select the edge and press <kbd>G</kbd>twice tp slide the edge)
Which will get u this:
[image]
To solve it in the proper way, you can apply the mirror modifier and box select the vertices and merge them with  <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > **merge at center** .(You wont even see the vertices cuz they are too close to each other).OR simply use the merge option in mirror modifier.

Comment: So when using the curve , the cuts should stay constant (not more here and less there) for the best result?

Comment: No What I meant was while using **mirror modifiers** the cuts should be constant

Comment: I recommend a cylinder to start with while creating it. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Ah so the mirror creates the problem,thanks

Comment: You can select the answer as the accepted one if that helped you. Or else your question will be marked un answered. Happy that you found it helpfull ; )

Comment: Also I tried starting with a cylinder but it is so mutch easier to work on flat surface and then curve it, because Im going to add more detail via booleans

Comment: Indeed that helped, thank you

Comment: Talking about booleans they too  can ruin up your topology . Those modifiers comes at the cost of the topology . You have to manually clean them up.

Comment: I understand that, I'm constantly working on improving these sort of skills